# libusbmuxd and libimobiledevice: circular reference?

Tags: macos, installation, libusb

When I try to install `libimobiledevice`, it says:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libusbmuxd >= 0.1.4) were not met:
No package 'libusbmuxd' found
```

But when I try to install [`libusbmuxd`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd) first, it says:

```
configure: error: preflight worker support requested but libimobiledevice could not befound
```

It seems that both packages require that the other one is already installed.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

libusbmuxd was recently split from usbmuxd. Install, in order, libplist 1.11, libusbmuxd 1.0.9, libimobiledevice 1.1.6 and then you can install usbmuxd.

Comment: can you please share tutorial link to learn how to compile in exe format?